# content query web part does not exist

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have a Team site and I want to add a content query web part in my site. But the content query web part is not appearing in the team site i active Team Collaboration Lists but content query web part but problem do not solve please help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate Publishing Feature in site collection features for CQWP to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the "Publishing infrastructure" at the Site Collection level is needed (at least at first) to get a hand on the CQWP. But sometimes you might not want to get yourself "loaded" with the overhead that Publishing Site add-up.

..and so you could still benefit from "re-using" it by exporting the Style Library (all XSLT on which CQWP depends are there) from a Site Collection Level having it already, and re-create that Library on the target "collaboration" site collection (always on the Top-Level site) and than simply go into Site Settings > Galleries > Web Parts catalog and add-it from there (is already installed if you have at least SharePoint Standard)!

Comment: Not to play devil advocate - actually I am pretty interested in the solution you are suggesting. Have you some pratical experience about using the wp without the publishing infrastructure? If my memory doesn't play triks I belive that the content query wp has some inner dependency to the publishing web site, not only to the style library. Did you notice any missbehaviour in the past?

Comment: I've been using it successfully in this manner, without any noticeable issues.